# Jquery and trying to get data from xml

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I want to get certain elements from an xml file but need to increment them on each request. I have this code but need to increment "'site:eq(0),site:eq(1),site:eq(2)'". So when I next click the more button it will load "'site:eq(3),site:eq(4),site:eq(5)'"
    $("#more").click(function(){

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sites.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('site:eq(0),site:eq(1),site:eq(2)').each(function(){
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                        var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                        $('<div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        $(this).find('desc').each(function(){
                            var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
                            var long = $(this).find('long').text();
                            $('<div class="brief"></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                            $('<div class="long"></div>').html(long).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            });
```

Thanks for any help in solving this

Answer (score 1):

Store the start-index in a variable(e.g. "start") and use this variable inside the selector:

```
'site:eq('+(start+0)'),site:eq('+(start+1)'),site:eq('+(start+2)')'
```

Comment: I've added that but for some reason it isn't working. First line of ajax call is...$(xml).find("site:eq('+(start+0)'),site:eq('+(start+1)'),site:eq('+(start+2)')").each(function(){

Comment: And where do you store/increment the variable "start"?

Comment: I needed to add parseInt() because it thought it was a string. One more problem is I need to increment each item by 4 as that is how many itme swill be loaded each time.